# What the scenario call fs.close is necessary

Tags: node.js, file-io

I can't find more about fs.close explain in nodejs API.
I want to know what the scenario call fs.close is necessary.
for example:

```
var fs =  require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/home/a.tex","abc"); or like fs.appendFile("/home/a.tex","close")
fs.close(); //is it necessary?
```

Are there any effects if i don't call fs.close?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You don't need to use `fs.close` after `fs.readFile`, `fs.writeFile`, or `fs.appendFile` as they don't return a `fd` (file descriptor). Those open the file, operate on it, and then close it for you.

The streams returned by `fs.createReadStream` and `fs.createWriteStream` close after the stream ends but may be closed early. If you have paused a stream, you must call close on the stream to close the `fd` or resume the stream and let it end after emitting all its data.

But if you call `fs.open` or any of the others that give a `fd`, you must eventually `fs.close` the `fd` that you are given.

Comment: May you describe the penalties that occur when you fail to call `close()`, why garbage collection doesn’t take care of this for you, and what type of programs/code/patterns would actually encounter issues when forgetting to call `fs.close()`?

Comment: What happens if `fd` goes out of scope? Will it close automatically or not?

Comment: @binki failing to close a file descriptor won't immediately cause issues, but there is a limit on how many file descriptors can be open at a time. So if you repeatedly open and fail to close file descriptors you will eventually get hit with an `EMFILE: too many open files` error.

Comment: @mpen the file descriptor will remain open even if it goes out of scope. It will not automatically close.

Comment: What if the main NodeJS process from which the `fs.open` was called is terminated?  Then does the OS consider the file handle still reserved?

Comment: You can call `fs.readFile`, `fs.writeFile`, and `fs.appendFile` with the first argument of a file descriptor (number). If you do, you should also call `fs.close` when you are done reading/writing/appending.

Comment: @Steverino, once a process exits, its resources will be released. In other words, the file handle will no longer be "reserved".