# fs.readstream to read an object and then pipe to writeable to file?

Tags: json, node.js, object, stream

Currently I have a module pulling sql results like this:

[{ID: 'test', NAME: 'stack'},{ID: 'test2', NAME: 'stack'}]

I want to just literally have that written to file so i can read it as an object later, but i want to write it by stream because some of the objects are really really huge and keeping them in memory isnt working anymore.

I am using mssql https://www.npmjs.org/package/mssql

and I am stuck at here:

```
    request.on('recordset', function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

how do I stream this out to a writable stream? I see options for object mode but i cant seem to figure out how to set it?

```
    request.on('recordset', function(result) {
        var readable = fs.createReadStream(result),
            writable = fs.createWriteStream("loadedreports/bot"+x[6]);
        readable.pipe(writable);
    });
```

this just errors because createReadStream must be a filepath...

am I on the right track here or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 1):

You´re almost on the right track: You just dont need a readable stream, since your data already arrives in chunks.

Then, you can just create the writeable stream OUTSIDE of the actual `'recordset'`-Event, else you would create a new stream everytime you get a new chunk (and this is not what you want).

Try it like this:

```
 var writable = fs.createWriteStream("loadedreports/bot"+x[6]);
 request.on('recordset', function(result) {
    writable.write(result);
 });
```

**EDIT**

If the recordset is already too big, use the `row`-Event:

```
   request.on('row', function(row) {
   // Same here
   });
```

Comment: I am receiving a type-error: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk

Comment: I added JSON.stringify(result) and then used that as my writable.write(stringified) and this seems to work. Obviously its changing my object but this will do I suppose. Now I gotta change how I am reading the file now. 

Thanks!

Comment: Well thats weird... Did you enable streaming by setting the option ` stream: true` (I guess so, else it probably wouldnt work)? Are you using the resultset or row-Event? Do you listen on the `done`-Event and then close the writestream?

Comment: That I did not do. I didnt know to listen to done and close the writestream. 

Something like this?   

request.on('done', function(end) {
   writable.close(end);
  });

Comment: Actually, reading this, I dont need to use fs.close. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176733/what-the-scenario-call-fs-close-is-necessary

What could be the problem then? I guess the MSSQL stream is still keeping each row after its written still. I need to drain the MSSQL part

Comment: Noticed a couple of other things,

writing on each row results in not a true json object. It doesnt finish by adding the [] around my objects nor the ,'s. I guess I need to write my own parser?

Additionally, requent.on('done') emits after the SQL query is finished, not after the stream is finished. I dont think I can solve the memory issue at this level. I might have to end up scrapping it or making my data smaller.

Comment: Hm im also out of ideas at that point, sorry. Maybe you can file an issue at the MSSQL-Github-Repo about this?