# Does fd need to be closed?

Tags: node.js

Does the file descriptor returned by [fs.open](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) need to be explictly [closed](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_close_fd_callback) or will it close itself once `fd` goes out of scope?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What the scenario call fs.close is necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176733/what-the-scenario-call-fs-close-is-necessary)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That doesn't answer what happens if `fd` goes out of scope.

Comment: I'm reading "But if you call fs.open or any of the others that give a fd, you must eventually fs.close the fd that you are given." as "you are on the hook for getting `close` called". If `fd` goes out of scope, you now have a file handle that can't be closed properly ever again.