# I have a .log file of objects how do I convert them to a JSON object for iterating through in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

Here is a sample of the .log file I need to convert.  I am using Node.

```
    {"test": "data", "test1": 123, "foo": "feel me??"}
    {"test": "data", "test1": 123, "foo": "feel me??"}
    {"test": "data", "test1": 123, "foo": "feel me??"}
```

I am importing it by using this code.

```
let data = fs.readFileSync(log_path, 'utf8', function(err, data){
  if (err) throw err;
  let tweets = data.split('\n').map(line => JSON.parse(line));

  return tweets;

  fs.close(data, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
})
```

As you can see it's not separated by commas so is not in JSON format.  I am trying to read the file, then split it by a new line, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `"feel me??"` is meant to be a property, you could `split` up the lines and then `map` them to an array of objects:

```js
const text = `    {"test": "data", "test1": 123, "foo": "feel me??"}
    {"test": "data", "test1": 123, "foo": "feel me??"}
    {"test": "data", "test1": 123, "foo": "feel me??"}`;
const arrOfObjs = text.split('\n')
  .map(line => JSON.parse(line));
console.log(arrOfObjs);
```

The other problem is that `readFileSync`, as its name implies, reads the file *synchronously*. It doesn't accept a callback like that. Change your file-reading code to:

```
let data = fs.readFileSync(log_path, 'utf8');
// do stuff with the `data` string
```

Remember that since you're not working with a stream, [you don't need `fs.close`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176733/what-the-scenario-call-fs-close-is-necessary).

Comment: When I use fs.readFileSync on the .log file it doesn't seem to return a string I can split up.

Comment: First time you mentioned that - then you should edit your question to clarify that, and post your code

Comment: Edited.  Sorry.  I thought it was implied saying I was reading from a .log file in that format.

Comment: See edit - `readFileSync` runs *synchronously*, not asynchronously. It doesn't accept a callback.

Comment: Sounds like the log text you're working with doesn't match the text you posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I used the `read-last-lines` package to get only a few last lines of my `log` file.

To make it work I had to slightly modify the code from the accepted answer, which was a great help for myself. I am going to add it here in case if someone was struggling with a similar issue.

```
readLastLines.read('info.log', 10)
      .then((lines) => {
        const arrOfStringObjs = lines.split('\n')
        let arrOfObjs = []
        arrOfStringObjs.forEach(strObj => {
          if (strObj !== undefined && strObj !== null && strObj !== '') {
            arrOfObjs.push(JSON.parse(strObj))
          }
        });
        console.log(arrOfObjs)
```

Hope it helps.