# How to close file descriptors in write streams

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code, which is a simplified example of what I am trying to do:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var stream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/file');
stream.once('open', function(fd) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
        stream.write('' + i + "\n");
    }
    stream.end();
    stream.close();
});
```

I can see that `fd` is the file descriptor and I wanted to close it. I called `fd.close()`, but that is not a method.

Two questions:

1. Should I be closing it?
2. How do I close it?

I saw some documentation on [`fs.close()` and `fs.closeSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_close_fd_callback). Should I use that?

Thanks.

Comment: I thinks this [what-the-scenario-call-fs-close-is-necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21177492/7967469) answers your first question and the docs answers your second question.

Comment: The docs for [`Class: fs.WriteStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_writestream) does not mention the `end()` or `close()` methods.

Comment: But `WriteStream` is a `WritableStream` ... Have a look at its docs too ...

Comment: The [`WriteableStream` docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) mentions the `end()` method, but says nothing about closing file descriptors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I called `fd.close()`

From the documentation you linked:

> fd  Integer file descriptor used by the WriteStream.

So `fd` is an integer, not an object with methods.

> Should I be closing it?

Yes! Otherwise you are wasting ressources, as the stream is pending. You should *end the stream*, by calling [`.end()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback). That will also close the underlying file, so there is no need to manually `fs.close` it.

Comment: Thanks. So what does `stream.close()` do? I can't find it in the docs. Can I remove it?

Comment: I can't find it too. Are you sure that it even exists?

Comment: I am not sure it exists! Weird that it doesn't break with it in there.

Comment: The fact that `stream.end()` is really doing the closing is what answers my question. Thank you.